# What does 'tests too big' warning in bazel mean?

Tags: bazel

I frequently get this message while running `bazel test //...`

```
There were tests whose specified size is too big.   
Use the --test_verbose_timeout_warnings command line option to see which ones these are.
```

What does 'size is too big' mean? As in what does 'size' refer to here? And why does 'big' matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you that the declared timeout is "too long". I find it a nuisance warning and ignore it, because it's often impossible to set timeouts somewhere that doesn't trigger this warning when it's the last test running on a fast CI machine, but doesn't time out on much slower developer laptops or heavily loaded CI machines.

The [test encyclopedia] gives a default mapping between sizes and timeouts, and the "recommended lower bounds" which trigger that warning. [--test_timeout](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--test_timeout) can modify those values. Also individual test targets can use the [timeout](https://bazel.build/reference/be/common-definitions#test.timeout) attribute to override it.

The wording of the message is from before timeouts were supported as a separate concept from the sizes, which also default several other job-scheduling-related values. The [common rule definitions for tests](https://bazel.build/reference/be/common-definitions#common-attributes-tests) docs have more details on that.